# How to keep CSV headers on the chunk files after script split?

Tags: python, csv

I need help on modifying this script to include headers on the output files chunks. The script uses some input to determined how many rows per file will the process split the file by. The output files does not contain headers from the original file. I'm am seeking advice on how to implement.

```
import csv
import os
import sys


os_path = os.path
csv_writer = csv.writer
sys_exit = sys.exit


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        chunk_size = int(input('Input number of rows of one chunk file: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Number of rows must be integer. Close.')
        sys_exit()

    file_path = input('Input path to .tsv file for splitting on chunks: ')

    if (
        not os_path.isfile(file_path) or
        not file_path.endswith('.tsv')
    ):
        print('You must input path to .tsv file for splitting.')
        sys_exit()

    file_name = os_path.splitext(file_path)[0]

    with open(file_path, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as tsv_file:

        chunk_file = None
        writer = None
        counter = 1
        reader = csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter='\t', quotechar='\'')

        for index, chunk in enumerate(reader):

            if index % chunk_size == 0:

                if chunk_file is not None:
                    chunk_file.close()

                chunk_name = '{0}_{1}.tsv'.format(file_name, counter)
                chunk_file = open(chunk_name, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
                counter += 1
                writer = csv_writer(chunk_file, delimiter='\t', quotechar='\'')

                print('File "{}" complete.'.format(chunk_name))

            writer.writerow(chunk)
```

Comment: How about just before `reader = ...` do, `hdr = tsv_file.readline()` and then feed `hdr` back for each chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by reading the header row manually when opening the input file, and then writing it at the beginning of each output file — see the `ADDED` comments in the code below:

```
...
with open(file_path, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as tsv_file:

    chunk_file = None
    writer = None
    counter = 1
    reader = csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter='\t', quotechar="'")
    header = next(reader)  # Read and save header row.  (ADDED)

    for index, chunk in enumerate(reader):
        if index % chunk_size == 0:
            if chunk_file is not None:
                chunk_file.close()

            chunk_name = '{0}_{1}.tsv'.format(file_name, counter)
            chunk_file = open(chunk_name, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
            writer = csv_writer(chunk_file, delimiter='\t', quotechar="'")
            writer.writerow(header)  # ADDED.
            print('File "{}" complete.'.format(chunk_name))
            counter += 1

        writer.writerow(chunk)
```

**Note** that using single-quote characters for quoting means the output files are not adhering to the CSV standard: [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance on this modification.